# Load data into pandas dataframe from zip file

Tags: python, pandas, api, zip

I am working to load data into pandas dataframe from downloaded zip file using REST API. I am able to load the file into dataframe if I know the name of the file using the following code:

```
z=zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(request_download.content))
df=pd.read_csv(z.open('Test1-RB.csv'))
print(df)
```

Is there a way that I can load the data into the dataframe without specifying the filename?
I am trying to do something like this:

```
z=zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(request_download.content))
df=pd.read_csv(z,compression="zip")
print(df)
```

but I am getting following error on trying to do that

> Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'zipfile.ZipFile'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this through the following code. I am not entering any filename on this now.

```
z=zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(request_download.content))
dfs=[]
for file in z.namelist():
  dfs.append(pd.read_csv(z.open(file),sep=';'))
df1 = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df1)
```